# trouble finding the sum of (1+2+...n)^2?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out what went wrong in my formula for sum2. It should be equal to sum1, which is equal to 784. The formula for sum2 = (1 + 2 + … + n)^2. Currently with this code I get sum2 is equal to 140. Can anyone tell me how I should fix this problem? Or give a hint

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double n = 7;
   double sum1 = 0; 
   double sum2 = 0; 
   double sum3 = 0; 
   double sum4 = 0;
   double i = 1;

   while(i <= n){

           sum1 = sum1 + pow(i,3);
           sum2 = sum2 + (i)*(i);
           i++;
}             

           sum3 = (pow(n,2)*pow((n + 1),2)) / 4;
           sum4 = n*(n+1)*(2*n + 1) / (4+2);
```

This is only half of the code

Comment: `sum1` and `sum2` are calculated in different ways, sum1 is added to by `i^3` whereas `sum2` is added to by `i*i = i^2`.

Comment: Hint: (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ... + 7^2) is not the same as (1 + 2 + 3 ... + 7) ^ 2.

Comment: Your code is calculating the wrong number. And there is a simple formula to calculate the sum of the first N natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(i <= n){

           sum1 = sum1 + pow(i,3);
           sum2 = sum2 + i;
           i++;
}
sum2 = sum2*sum2;
```

Missed the error in sum1 computation.
@FreeNickname nailed it - that is the correct answer.

Comment: Missed the error in sum1 computation. @FreeNickname nailed it - that is the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

First, your code for `sum1` currently finds
`1 ^ 3 + 2 ^ 3 + ... + n ^ 3` instead of `(1 + 2 + ... n) ^ 2`

Second, your code for `sum2` currently finds
`1 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 2 + ... + n ^ 2` instead of `(1 + 2 + ... n) ^ 2`

In order to fix it, change 2 lines inside the `while` loop:

```
while(i <= n){
   sum1 = sum1 + i;
   sum2 = sum2 + i; //or, since they are the same now, you can accumulate the sum in sun1 and then do sum2 = sum1 outside the while loop.
   i++;
}
```

And then after it use whatever technique you want to calculate a square:

```
sum1 = pow(sum1, 2); //2, not 3
sum2 = sum2 * sum2;
```

Comment: Or calculate `n*(n+1)/2.0` and square that number.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes, thank you for the suggestion :) Arithmetic progression (for those who's interested, where that formula came from).

Answer (score 1):

you have to find `(1 + 2 + 3 ... + 7) ^ 2`. not `(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ... + 7^2)` so multiply `sum2` after addition is done `till n=7;`

so inside while do:

```
 sum2 = sum2 + i;
```

and out side of while do:

```
sum2 = sum2*sum2;
```

change your code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double n = 7;
   double sum1 = 0; 
   double sum2 = 0; 
   double sum3 = 0; 
   double sum4 = 0;
   double i = 1;

   while(i <= n){

           sum1 = sum1 + i;
           sum2 = sum2 + i;
           i++;
}             
cout<<pow(sum1, 2);// both will be same
cout<<sum2*sum2;
           sum3 = (pow(n,2)*pow((n + 1),2)) / 4;
           sum4 = n*(n+1)*(2*n + 1) / (4+2);

}
```